# Creating a basic pie chart in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, charts, pie-chart

I am having issues trying to resolve why my chart control isn't working correctly.  I have never worked with Pie Charts before, and I can't get a basic pie chart to populate.  Ultimately, I am trying to create an exploded pie chart with percentages (if possible)

My code so far is:

```
chrtRegisterAvailability.Series.Clear()
chrtRegisterAvailability.Series.Add("Series1")
chrtRegisterAvailability.Series("Series1").Points.AddXY("Online", 60)
chrtRegisterAvailability.Series("Series1").Points.AddXY("Offline", 40)
chrtRegisterAvailability.Series("Series1").ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie
chrtRegisterAvailability.Series("Series1")("PieLabelStyle") = "Outside"
chrtRegisterAvailability.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").Area3DStyle.Enable3D = True
chrtRegisterAvailability.Series.Add("Series1")
```

No doubt I am missing something as I've tried finding various examples on the net, but with no luck.  Any help appreciated thanks.

Comment: If this is the actual code you should at least drop the last line. The item named "Series1" have already been added to the series collection.

Comment: I have removed the last line of code, but I still get a blank chart box control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. It might be that not clearing the chart is the issue.

```
    With Me.chrtRegisterAvailability
        .Legends.Clear()
        .Series.Clear()
        .ChartAreas.Clear()
    End With

    Dim areas1 As ChartArea = Me.chrtRegisterAvailability.ChartAreas.Add("Areas1")

    With areas1
    End With

    Dim series1 As Series = Me.chrtRegisterAvailability.Series.Add("Series1")

    With series1
        .ChartArea = areas1.Name
        .ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie
        .Points.AddXY("Online", 60)
        .Points.AddXY("Offline", 40)
    End With

    Dim legends1 As Legend = Me.chrtRegisterAvailability.Legends.Add("Legends1")
```

Comment: Okay, your code was helpful thankyou.  However, the actual fault of my problem was that I was trying to populate the chart control through a thread - giving me cross thread errors.  I found the actual fix here: [link](http://notesbyparth.wordpress.com/2013/12/10/loadfillpopulate-chart-with-backgroundworker-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 0):

1. Open New VB.Net Project
2. Place Panel1 on Form
   Location 604,76
   Size 600,600
3. Place Panel2 on Form
   Location 9,75
   Size 659,577
   copy and paste code

   Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks

   Public Class Form1

   ## Region "Data"

   ```
   Public Colors() As Color
   Public Data(), Degree(359) As Double
   Public EArc(), CArc(), Parts(), PieSize(), Radius, SArc() As Integer
   Public Labels(0, 3) As Label
   Public Center, ECenter() As Point
   Public sc As New ShapeContainer
   Private GLine(360) As LineShape
   Public LabelNamess(), TitleName As String
   Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
       Radius = 246
       Center.X = 300
       Center.Y = 300
       Dim count As Integer = -1
       For x = 270 To 359
           count = count + 1
           Degree(count) = 0.01745 * (x)
       Next
       For x = 0 To 269
           count = count + 1
           Degree(count) = 0.01745 * (x)
       Next
       Dim c(12) As Color
       c(0) = Color.Black
       c(1) = Color.Red
       c(2) = Color.DarkSlateBlue
       c(3) = Color.Yellow
       c(4) = Color.Green
       c(5) = Color.Blue
       c(6) = Color.Purple
       c(7) = Color.Navy
       c(8) = Color.Brown
       c(9) = Color.Cyan
       c(10) = Color.DarkGreen
       c(11) = Color.DarkRed
       c(12) = Color.HotPink
       Colors = c
       Dim p(12) As Double
       p(0) = 5696
       p(1) = 5495.99
       p(2) = 6016.99
       p(3) = 5168.99
       p(4) = 5421.99
       p(5) = 6030.99
       p(6) = 4810.99
       p(7) = 5199.99
       p(8) = 4716.0
       p(9) = 4095.95
       p(10) = 3299.99
       p(11) = 4562.19
       p(12) = 5267.38
       Data = p
       Dim s(12) As String
       s(0) = "January 2014"
       s(1) = "Febuary 2014"
       s(2) = "March 2014"
       s(3) = "April 2014"
       s(4) = "May 2014"
       s(5) = "June 2014"
       s(6) = "July 2014"
       s(7) = "August 2014"
       s(8) = "September 2014"
       s(9) = "October 2014"
       s(10) = "November 2014"
       s(11) = "December 2014"
       s(12) = "January 2015"
       LabelNamess = s
       TitleName = "Monthly Graph for 2014"
       CreatePieGraph()
   End Sub
   ```

   ## End Region

   ## Region "Pie Graph"

   ```
   Public Sub CreatePieGraph()
       Title.Text = TitleName
       Title.Left = 639 - Int(Title.Width / 2)
       DrawGraph()
       PieLabels()

   End Sub
   Public Sub PieLabels()
       ReDim Labels(Data.Length - 1, 3)
       Dim per As Double
       For x = 0 To LabelNamess.GetLength(0) - 1
           Dim l As New Label
           l.Left = 20
           l.Top = 50 + (40 * x)
           l.Width = 240
           l.Height = 24
           l.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 14.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
           l.Text = LabelNamess(x)
           l.Name = "L0" & x
           Labels(x, 0) = l
           Panel2.Controls.Add(l)
           Dim l1 As New Label
           l1.Left = 275
           l1.Top = 50 + (40 * x)
           l1.Width = 20
           l1.Height = 24
           l1.BackColor = Colors(x)
           l1.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 14.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
           l1.Text = ""
           l1.Name = "L1" & x
           Labels(x, 1) = l1
           Panel2.Controls.Add(l1)
           Dim l2 As New Label
           l2.Left = 315
           l2.Top = 50 + (40 * x)
           l2.Width = 90
           l2.Height = 24
           l2.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 14.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
           per = (PieSize(x) / 360) * 100
           l2.Text = Format(per, "###.###") & "%"
           l2.Name = "L2" & x
           Labels(x, 2) = l2
           Panel2.Controls.Add(l2)
           Dim l3 As New Label
           l3.Left = 425
           l3.Top = 50 + (40 * x)
           l3.Width = 140
           l3.Height = 24
           l3.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 14.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
           per = (PieSize(x) / 252) * 100
           l3.Text = Format(Data(x), "$#,###,###,###.00")
           l3.Name = "L3" & x
           Labels(x, 3) = l3
           Panel2.Controls.Add(l3)
       Next

   End Sub
   Private Function PiceSize(RawData() As Double) As Array
       Dim Dsum As Double
       Dim ps As Integer = RawData.Length - 1
       Dim count, z, size0(ps), size1(ps), size2(ps), size3(ps), max As Integer
       Dim sizes(2) As Array
       For x = 0 To RawData.GetLength(0) - 1
           Dsum = Dsum + RawData(x)
       Next
       For x = 0 To ps
           size0(x) = Int((RawData(x) / Dsum) * 360)
           If ((RawData(x) / Dsum) * 360) - size0(x) > 0.49999 Then size0(x) = size0(x) + 1
           count = count + size0(x)
       Next
       z = -1
       If count < 360 Then
           For x = count + 1 To 360
               z = z + 1
               If z > sizes.GetLength(0) Then z = 0
               size0(z) = size0(z) + 1
               count = count + 1
           Next
       End If
       If count > 360 Then
           For x = count - 1 To 360 Step -1
               z = z + 1
               If z > sizes.GetLength(0) Then z = 0
               size0(z) = size0(z) - 1
               count = count - 1
           Next
       End If
       count = 0
       For x = 0 To ps
           If x = 0 Then size1(x) = 0
           If x = 0 Then size2(x) = size0(x)
           If x = 0 Then size3(x) = Int(size0(x) / 2)
           If x <> 0 Then size1(x) = count
           If x <> 0 Then size2(x) = count + size0(x)
           If x <> 0 Then size3(x) = size1(x) + Int(size0(x) / 2)
           If x = ps Then size2(x) = size2(x)
           count = count + size0(x)
       Next
       SArc = size1
       EArc = size2
       CArc = size3
       PiceSize = size0

   End Function
   Private Sub DrawGraph()
       Dim x1, y1, z, p As Integer
       Dim sizes(Data.GetLength(0) - 1) As Integer
       Dim ps As Integer = Data.GetLength(0) - 1
       Dim Ecenter1(ps) As Point
       PieSize = PiceSize(Data)
       z = 1
       sc.Height = 600
       sc.Width = 600
       sc.Top = 74
       sc.Left = 608
       For num As Double = 0 To 359
           x1 = Convert.ToInt32(Radius * Math.Cos(Degree(num)) + Center.X)
           y1 = Convert.ToInt32(Radius * Math.Sin(Degree(num)) + Center.Y)
           If num = CArc(p) Then
               Ecenter1(p).X = Convert.ToInt32(50 * Math.Cos(Degree(num)) + Center.X)
               Ecenter1(p).Y = Convert.ToInt32(50 * Math.Sin(Degree(num)) + Center.Y)
           End If
           Dim Line As New LineShape
           Line.X1 = Center.X
           Line.Y1 = Center.Y
           Line.X2 = x1
           Line.Y2 = y1
           Line.BorderColor = Colors(p)
           Line.BorderWidth = 5
           Line.Visible = True
           Line.Name = "line" & Chr(p + 65) & z
           If z = PieSize(p) Then
               p = p + 1
               z = 0
           End If
           z = z + 1
           GLine(num) = Line
           AddHandler Line.MouseHover, AddressOf CicrleHover
           AddHandler Line.MouseLeave, AddressOf CicrleLeave
           AddHandler Line.Click, AddressOf ExplodePice
           AddHandler Line.DoubleClick, AddressOf ChangeColor
           sc.Shapes.Add(Line)
       Next
       ECenter = Ecenter1
       Panel1.Controls.Add(sc)

   End Sub
   ```

   ## End Region

   ## Region "EVents"

   ```
   Protected Sub CicrleHover(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
       Dim o As LineShape = sender
       Dim n As String = o.Name
       Dim s As Integer = Asc(Mid(n, 5, 1)) - 65
       For x = 0 To 3
           If x <> 1 Then
               Labels(s, x).BackColor = Color.Black
               Labels(s, x).ForeColor = Color.White
           End If
       Next

   End Sub
   Protected Sub CicrleLeave(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
       Dim o As LineShape = sender
       Dim n As String = o.Name
       Dim s As Integer = Asc(Mid(n, 5, 1)) - 65
       For x = 0 To 3
           If x <> 1 Then
               Labels(s, x).BackColor = Color.White
               Labels(s, x).ForeColor = Color.Black
           End If
       Next

   End Sub
   Protected Sub ExplodePice(Sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
       Dim o As LineShape = Sender
       Dim n As String = o.Name
       Dim s As Integer = Asc(Mid(n, 5, 1)) - 65
       Dim x1, y1 As Integer
       Dim cpoint As Point
       If o.X1 = Center.X Then cpoint = ECenter(s) Else cpoint = Center
       For x = SArc(s) To EArc(s) - 1
           x1 = Convert.ToInt32(Radius * Math.Cos(Degree(x)) + cpoint.X)
           y1 = Convert.ToInt32(Radius * Math.Sin(Degree(x)) + cpoint.Y)
           GLine(x).X2 = x1
           GLine(x).Y2 = y1
           GLine(x).X1 = cpoint.X
           GLine(x).Y1 = cpoint.Y
       Next
   End Sub
   Protected Sub ChangeColor(Sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
       Dim o As LineShape = Sender
       Dim n As String = o.Name
       Dim s As Integer = Asc(Mid(n, 5, 1)) - 65
       ColorDialog1.ShowDialog()
       For x = SArc(s) To EArc(s) - 1
           GLine(x).BorderColor = ColorDialog1.Color
       Next
       Labels(s, 1).BackColor = ColorDialog1.Color
   End Sub
   ```

   ## End Region

   End Class